# C# Add 1 day in specific TimeZone to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, datetimeoffset, .net-4.6

I have an instance of `DateTimeOffset` and I need to add 1 day to it in specific `TimeZone` (W. Europe Standard Time) taking into account daylight saving rules (so it might result in `Offset` change). How can I do it without 3rd party libraries?

Verifiable example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TimeZoneTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DateTimeOffsetAddDays_DaylightSaving_OffsetChange()
        {
            var timeZoneId = "W. Europe Standard Time";
            var utcTimestamp = new DateTimeOffset(2017, 10, 28, 22, 0, 0, TimeZoneInfo.Utc.BaseUtcOffset);
            var weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcTimestamp, timeZoneId);
            Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2017, 10, 29), weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp.DateTime);
            Assert.AreEqual(TimeSpan.FromHours(2), weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp.Offset);

            var weuropeStandardTimeTimestampNextDay = AddDaysInTimeZone(weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp, 1, timeZoneId);

            Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2017, 10, 30), weuropeStandardTimeTimestampNextDay);
            Assert.AreEqual(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp.Offset);
        }

        private DateTimeOffset AddDaysInTimeZone(DateTimeOffset timestamp, int days, string timeZoneId)
        {
            // this line has to be fixed:
            return timestamp.AddDays(days);
        }
    }
}
```

`AddDaysInTimeZone` method should be replaced with correct implementation.

PS If it results in invalid/ambigous/skipped date, then it is fine to throw exception.

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what you mean, ideally with a [mcve]. Does the `DateTimeOffset` contain an offset which is definitely valid for the time zone in question? What do you want to do if adding a day results in an ambiguous or skipped time? (Imagine it's 1:30am the day *before* the clocks go back or forward at 2am or 1am respectively. What do you want adding a day to do?)

Comment: If you mean without "non-Microsoft" libraries, I suspect the answer is no: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/performing-arithmetic-operations

Comment: @DylanNicholson: I'm sure with a small amount of code it should be feasible using `TimeZoneInfo`. (It would be *better* with Noda Time of course, but that's a different matter.) But we need a really precise set of requirements first - there's no point in trying before then.

Comment: Added Verifiable example to question.

Comment: That's not really a [mcve] - we can't copy/paste/compile/run. But more importantly, you haven't addressed my questions about whether the offset is definitely valid in the first place, and what you want to do with ambiguous/skipped times. I'm not going to put time into writing code which might not work for your *actual*, unstated, requirements.

Comment: Yes, we can assume that original DateTimeOffset instance has valid Offset for "W. Europe Standard Time" time zone (eg `weuropeStandardTimeTimestamp` in sample). If it results in amiguous/skipped times - exception should be thrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TimeZoneInfo` makes this *reasonably* simple - just add a day to the `DateTime` part of the value, check whether the result is skipped or ambiguous, and if not, ask the zone for the UTC offset. Here's a complete example showing all the different possibilities:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

using static System.FormattableString;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {        
        // Stay in winter
        Test("2017-01-22T15:00:00+01:00");
        // Skipped time during transition
        Test("2017-03-25T02:30:00+01:00");
        // Offset change to summer
        Test("2017-03-25T15:00:00+01:00");
        // Stay in summer
        Test("2017-06-22T15:00:00+02:00");
        // Ambiguous time during transition
        Test("2017-10-28T02:30:00+02:00");
        // Offset change back to winter
        Test("2017-10-28T15:00:00+02:00");
        // Stay in winter
        Test("2017-12-22T15:00:00+01:00");
    }

    static void Test(string startText)
    {
        var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
        var start = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
            startText, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        try
        {
            var end = AddOneDay(start, zone);
            Console.WriteLine(Invariant($"{startText} => {end:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK}"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{startText} => {e.Message}");
        }
    }

    static DateTimeOffset AddOneDay(DateTimeOffset start, TimeZoneInfo zone)
    {
        var newLocal = start.DateTime.AddDays(1);
        // TODO: Use a better exception type :)
        if (zone.IsAmbiguousTime(newLocal))
        {
            throw new Exception("Ambiguous");
        }
        if (zone.IsInvalidTime(newLocal))
        {
            throw new Exception("Skipped");
        }
        return new DateTimeOffset(newLocal, zone.GetUtcOffset(newLocal));
    }

}
```