# Create new DateTime in Country via TimeZoneInfo for office hours

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

## Question

### Q: How can I create a DateTime for e.g. 09:00 in Europe/Vienna

Catch: Most solutions that I've found already take a DateTime object and convert it but I want to CREATE it IN A SPECIFIC timezone knowing the timezone.

So it is not DateTimeKind.Utc and it is not DateTimeKind.Local it would be in DateTime in timezone.

## Problem

### P: TimeZoneInfo is not a parameter of DateTime. Why not? Could there be a simple extension?

---

**Basis data:**

```
1. string From = "09:00" //local time because summertime/wintertime
2. string Till = "17:00" //local time because summertime/wintertime
3. string TimeZoneResolved = "Europe/Vienna"
```

**Implicitly I have:**

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneResolved);
TimeSpan workHoursStart = TimeSpan.Parse(From);
TimeSpan workHoursEnd = TimeSpan.Parse(Till);
```

**What I want to achieve:**

```
//reconstruct today 9am in that country of timeZoneInfo
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var startTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, workHoursStart.Hour, workHoursStart.Minute, 0, 0, timeZoneInfo);
```

-> invalid because TimeZoneInfo parameter is invalid. Expects DateTimeKind

**Because constructor overload might be tricky maybe like that**

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var officeHoursStart = new DateTime().BasedOnTz(timeZoneInfo, now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, workHoursStart.Hour, workHoursStart.Minute, 0, 0);
var officeHoursStartUtc = officeHoursStart.ToUtc();
```

Comment: Note, your pseudo code is not correct because the UTC date may not necessarily be the same date in effect for the given time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restate the problem - you have as input a time and a time zone, and you need as output the point in time that corresponds to that time on the current day in the given time zone.

Since the output is a point in time, you should prefer using `DateTimeOffset`. (If you must use a `DateTime`, you can take the `.DateTime` property from that.)

Since the input is a time of day, you should prefer using `TimeOnly`, available in .NET 6 and higher.  (If you're using older .NET, then use a `TimeSpan`.)

Here's the general approach:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

// Get the time zone as a TimeZoneInfo object, either directly or via TimeZoneConverter.
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eurpope/Vienna");

// Parse the time string.  Prefer using TimeOnly (.NET 6+).
string timeString = "17:00";
TimeOnly time = TimeOnly.ParseExact(timeString, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Or use TimeSpan on older .NET
// TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeString, "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Get the time on "today" with respect to the given time zone
DateTimeOffset timeTodayInTimeZone = time.OnTodayInTimeZone(timeZone);
```

You'll need some extension methods.  Pick one of these, depending on which input you're using.

```
public static DateTimeOffset OnTodayInTimeZone(this TimeOnly time, TimeZoneInfo tz) =>
    DateOnly.FromDateTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz))
        .ToDateTime(time)
        .ToDateTimeOffset(tz);

public static DateTimeOffset OnTodayInTimeZone(this TimeSpan time, TimeZoneInfo tz) =>
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz).Date
        .Add(time)
        .ToDateTimeOffset(tz);
```

And finally, you need this extension method that has the bulk of the logic.
(I've used this one on [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961386/634824) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866718/634824) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59960087/634824) [now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457953/634824).)

```
public static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(this DateTime dt, TimeZoneInfo tz)
{
    if (dt.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        // Handle UTC or Local kinds (regular and hidden 4th kind)
        DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt.ToUniversalTime(), TimeSpan.Zero);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, tz);
    }

    if (tz.IsAmbiguousTime(dt))
    {
        // Prefer the daylight offset, because it comes first sequentially (1:30 ET becomes 1:30 EDT)
        TimeSpan[] offsets = tz.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(dt);
        TimeSpan offset = offsets[0] > offsets[1] ? offsets[0] : offsets[1];
        return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
    }

    if (tz.IsInvalidTime(dt))
    {
        // Advance by the gap, and return with the daylight offset  (2:30 ET becomes 3:30 EDT)
        TimeSpan[] offsets = { tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(-1)), tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(1)) };
        TimeSpan gap = offsets[1] - offsets[0];
        return new DateTimeOffset(dt.Add(gap), offsets[1]);
    }

    // Simple case
    return new DateTimeOffset(dt, tz.GetUtcOffset(dt));
}
```

Comment: Sorry took me a while to be back on this topic. Saved my ass. Thanks a lot!